# Unable to send any messages when iMessages deselected

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

In my iMessage settings, the settings for

> You can receive iMessages to and and reply from

only have my own phone and email address. Nothing was picked up from my [300] Contacts for some reason.  So that's not useful.

Given that, I have turned off iMessage.  That still does not work: any messages attempted to be sent come back with the red **!** as *Not Delivered*.

What I'm looking for:

- use iMessage for the majority of my contacts that are using iPhones
- use SMS for everyone else.

The iPhone 6 from which I [otherwise] successfully restored the apps and settings allowed this to happen. What might need to be tweaked on this newly set up phone to get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, now it's working [with no changes made].  Looks like the installation process was actually still running. Even though Messages were installed and the messages history was already available, *sending* messages was not yet enabled.